# Regex check if string only has numbers after last instance of character and before last instance of another

Tags: regex, url, iis

I'm trying to write a particular regex pattern for a rewrite rule in IIS and if it matches the pattern to stop processing any more rules.

The Url will look something like this:

somesite.com/somepath/34343.aspx

I need to see if I only have numbers in the section 34343 as I can have 
somesite.com/somepath/something343.aspx

I have tried matching the pattern like so:
([0-9]*).aspx$
But this picks up the latter URL and stops processing the rules so later matches aren't run. I need them to run on the later rules and not stop processing.

So if anyone can help, I need some way to check if I only have numbers after the last trailing slash and before the last .(dot)

I have also tried this:
(.*)/(.*).(.*)
which seems to give me what I want, inasmuch as it gives me grouped matches:

- Full Match- somesite.com/somepath/34343.aspx
- Group 1- somesite.com/somepath
- Group 2- 34343
- Group 3- aspx

But I don't know how to use Group 2 to then check that text for only numbers?

Can anyone help please?

Thanks

*EDIT*

Thanks for the replies, but these two patterns aren't working for me. I plug them into the IIS Url rewrite tool and whilst the rather wonderful test pattern option tells me that they match, they rule just doesn't fire.

```
<rule name="Ignore id with aspx" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^(.*\/\d+\..+)$" ignoreCase="true" />
    <!--OR-->
    <match url="^.*\/\d+\.[^.]+$" ignoreCase="true" />        
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false" />
</rule>
```

Or at least it doesn't stop processing anymore subsequent rules.

Coincidentally, the rule I said I was using ([0-9]*).aspx$ does fire and does stop processing the subsequent rules.

Comment: Try [`^.*/\d+\.[^.]+$`](https://regex101.com/r/V08NkK/1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the help, but I managed to figure out why it wasn't firing the rule and it appears to now be working.

I setup Failed Request Tracing Rules and noticed that the rule had removed the base url http://somesite.com/ from the check. So it was only looking for the last bit of the Url.

As the Url's in question were http://somesite.com/12345.apsx it was easy to then check for just numbers and .aspx in the request.

```
<rule name="Ignore id with aspx" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^\d*\..+[aspx]" ignoreCase="true" /> 
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false" />
    <action type="None" />
</rule>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make the regex like this:

```
(.*\/)+(\d*\..+)
```

This will check if it contains only digits.